# Do D3D11 / Metal / Vulcan programs commonly use upload/buffer threads?

Tags: directx11, metal

I am porting an older OpenGL ES 2 program to more modern APIs (DX11/Metal/Vulkan, let's say.) The existing code uses a dedicated uploading/buffering thread (via a "share context") to upload texture data, so as to allow the rendering thread to run within frame budget. At times there can be small hundreds of MB of texture data to upload.

Do modern programs ever use a dedicated upload thread? Is it even possible to do so for D3D / Metal / Vulkan?

Comment: I would recommend not asking questions of the form "is it common to do X?" It does not matter whether or not it's common. If it's helpful for your case, it's helpful for your case, even if no one else on the planet does it that way. So, try to phrase the question in terms of your own use case, not what might be common/uncommon for other people's use cases.

Comment: DX11/12/Metal/Vulkan are all modern enough that they were designed for multi-core CPUs and multi-threading. The idea of using a "share context" is more specific to older APIs where contexts couldn't be accessed from multiple threads so you would have to create a context for each thread and share resources between them. The concept of using multiple threads is something that these newer APIs improve upon and you should take advantage of it if you need it.